# Are there ways getting sequence of executed statements in target C program?

Tags: c, sequence, trace

I am trying to get sequence of executed statements in a target program written in C **after** executing the program, but I could not find the way.
I don't need to get sequence of executed statements during run-time.
Are there any ways to do that?
FYI, I know gcov reports statement coverage, but it does not report sequence of executed statements in a target program as far as I know (I want to get sequence of executed statements **only in target program source code**).
I am running C program in Linux with gcc compiler :)

For your clear understanding, see the following example.

When I execute following program I want to get sequence of executed statements as follows.

```
1: int main()
2: {
3:    int a  = 10;
4:    printf("hello");
5:    if( a == 10){
6:       printf("a == 0");
7:    }else{
8:       printf("a != 0");}
9:    return 0;
10: }
```

Output what I want to get is: **34569**
(Since target program what I want to trace has only one statement on a line, 
sequence of **line number** as output is enough for me)

This question was asked to others a few hours ago(see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048538/are-there-ways-getting-sequence-of-executed-statements-in-a-program-written-in-c)), but it was closed by a few readers without clear answers.
If it has well-known solution, please let me know.

Comment: If you ask same question twice, it's very likely that this will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: There is no way to trace a completed program. You will need to collect this information at run-time 1) by using trace facilities, or 2) by your own means.

Comment: The line numbers you see in the editor may not be the actual line numbers for what gets compiled. Pre-processor includes, macros and all manners of other *behind the scenes* stuff will definitely "interfere" and "change" your line numbers. In effect, the output would be barely useful and definitely not worth the hacks required to generate it. It would be better to attach a debugger and observe the program flow.

Comment: Source code does not execute. So you can not get this information. Binary executes. If you put line number information in the binary by `__LINE__` you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **LINE** preprocessor macro to get line number,

just add `printf("%d", __LINE__);` after each line

Comment: This will work for most cases, however this needs to be added manually & sensibly; since the line may not be simple statement line. e.g. you should not add it immediately after `for(i=0;i<10;i++)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But are there other ways that can do it automatically? Unfortunately, I knew this one but this requires manual efforts as anishsane describes in the above. I need to instrument more than 10 programs and some of them consists of more than 10000 lines.

Comment: i am not sure, but you can try using multi processing, create another process that can get the line number and print it on console. Though i am not sure and i am bit occupied right now with other stuff, will give it a try once free.